# Styling Javascript dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a working Javascript drop down, that pulls from a Json file. It works perfectly fine.

I'm trying to figure out how to style my buttons, and characteristics using Twitter Bootstrap 3.I know Bootstrap 3, I'm just confused on how to access my javascript components to style them at all.

This html calls my code in my index.html document

```
<div id='form-wrapper'></div>
```

And here is the Javascript / Json that determines the functionality of the dropdown.

```
// The JSON this is all pulled from
var json = {
    "Apple": {
        "A / C": {
            "weight": 6,
            "price": 3.99
        },
        "B": {
            "weight": 7,
            "price": 4.99
        }
    },
    "Orange": {
        "1": {
            "weight": 4,
            "price": 4.49
        },
        "2": {
            "weight": 5,
            "price": 5.49
        }
    }
};

// Correct JSON data
for (var a in json) {
    for (var attr in json[a]) {
        if (/\//.test(attr)) {
            var attrs = attr.split(/\s*\/\s*/);
            for (var x = 0, y = attrs.length; x < y; ++ x) {
                json[a][attrs[x]] = json[a][attr];
            }
            json[a][attr] = null;
        }
    }
}

var form_wrapper = document.getElementById("form-wrapper");

// Create the first dropdown
var dropdown1 = document.createElement("select");

// Populate the first dropdown
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "Select a fruit";
option.value = "none";
dropdown1.appendChild(option);

// Add options from JSON
for (var attr in json) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = option.value = attr;
    dropdown1.appendChild(option);
}

// Create the second dropdown
var dropdown2 = document.createElement("select");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "N/A";
dropdown2.appendChild(option);

// Add weight field
var weight = document.createElement("div");

// Add price field
var price = document.createElement("div");

// Function to automatically fill the weight/price fields
var auto_fill_fields = function() {

    if (dropdown1.value != "none") {
        var obj = json[dropdown1.value][dropdown2.value];
        var weight_str = "Weight: " + obj.weight + " oz";
        var price_str = "Price: $" + obj.price;
    } else {
        var weight_str = "Weight: N/A";
        var price_str = "Price: N/A";
    }

    weight.innerHTML = weight_str;
    price.innerHTML = price_str;
};

// Handle changing the first dropdown
dropdown1.addEventListener("change", function() {
    // Remove the current options from the second dropdown
    $(dropdown2).empty();

    // Did they actually select a fruit?
    if (this.value != "none") { // Yes
        // Populate the second dropdown
        var names = [];
        for (var attr in json[this.value]) {
            if (json[this.value][attr] == null) {
                continue;
            }
            names.push(attr);            
        }
        console.log(names);
        names = names.sort();
        console.log(names);
        for (var x = 0, y = names.length; x < y; ++ x) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.innerHTML = option.value = names[x];
            dropdown2.appendChild(option);
        }
    } else { // No
        // There's nothing to choose
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.innerHTML = "N/A";
        dropdown2.appendChild(option);
    }

    auto_fill_fields();
});

// Handle changing the second dropdown
dropdown2.addEventListener("change", auto_fill_fields);

// Fill in initial values
auto_fill_fields();

// Add submit button
var submit = document.createElement("button");
submit.innerHTML = "submit";
submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (dropdown1.value == "none") {
        return;
    }
    var obj = json[dropdown1.value][dropdown2.value];
    var weight_str = "Weight: " + obj.weight + " oz";
    var price_str = "Price: $" + obj.price;
    var request_str = dropdown1.value + " " + dropdown2.value + " - " + weight_str + ", " + price_str;
    console.log(request_str);
    $.ajax({
        url: "SOMEPLACE",
        data: {
            "key": request_str
        }
    });
});

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Add the first dropdown to the page (body)
form_wrapper.appendChild(dropdown1);
    // Add the second dropdown to the page (body)
    form_wrapper.appendChild(dropdown2);
    // And the rest
    form_wrapper.appendChild(weight);
    form_wrapper.appendChild(price);
    form_wrapper.appendChild(submit);
});
```

Comment: You style it the same way you would style anything else with CSS

Comment: Apply the form classes to your elements: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: @APAD1 Thank you for the valuable insight! When I do that I can see that I'm creating particular options / buttons. But how do I add classes to the html created by the javascript?

For example, when I create the option that contains "N/A", how do I incorporate a class into that?

Comment: @jme11 How do I add the form classes to my elements when I'm creating them in javascript?

Comment: Well, since you're using vanilla Javascript, you'd use: className, such as: dropdown1.className = "form-control".  If you were using jQuery, you'd just use the addClass method.  $('select').addClass('form-control').

Comment: @jme11 Thank you <3  dropdown1.className = "form-control". worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a super easy way without changing anything I had done. I simply put thee following after I declared the variable I wanted to style.

```
varName.className = "Class";
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript is creating HTML for you. If you have Chrome installed, right-click the dropdrop (control+click on a Mac) on your page and choose Inspect element from the menu. (Other browsers can do this as well. Most browsers show useful development tools when you press F12.)

This will allow you to explore the HTML being generated by your JavaScript.

**UPDATE:** Based on a followup question in the comments, here is one way to attach a class when values are N/A. This replaces the `auto_fill_fields` function in the original post.

```
// Function to automatically fill the weight/price fields
var auto_fill_fields = function() {

  if (dropdown1.value != "none") {
    var obj = json[dropdown1.value][dropdown2.value];
    var weight_str = "Weight: " + obj.weight + " oz";
    var price_str = "Price: $" + obj.price;
  } else {
    var weight_str = "Weight: N/A";
    var weight_class = "not-available";
    var price_str = "Price: N/A";
    var price_class = "not-available";
  }

  weight.innerHTML = weight_str;
  if (weight_class) {
    weight.className = weight_class;
  }
  price.innerHTML = price_str;
  if (price_class) {
    price.className = price_class;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable insight! When I do that I can see that I'm creating particular options / buttons. But how do I add classes to the html created by the javascript?

For example, when I create the option that contains "N/A", how do I incorporate a class into that?

Comment: You'll have to update the JavaScript in order to add a class. I updated the answer above with one possible solution.